# Can Dell SonicWall NetExtender record urls visited

Tags: vpn, dell, sonicwall

My company is in geographical different area and I am in a different area. They have asked me to install VPN client **Dell SonicWall NetExtender**

I want to know if I am connected to it can they track which websites I am visitingr or is this not possible?

I did a tracert and my packets are going to appropriate locations without being sent to them. However, I want to know if this is really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to *set it up* they way you're asking about, but the tracert shows they're not doing this.  With almost any VPN, there is a choice between sending **all** traffic through the VPN, or sending only necessary traffic through the VPN.  Bandwidth costs money, and none of the companies I've serviced care what websites employees visit when out of the office.

If they have an IT guy/gal/team, you could just ask one of them.  Unless they're socially inept or you're a jerk, they'll be straight with you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't believe tracert, why would you believe the word of psuedonymous strangers? Maybe we work for your employer and are conspiring to mislead you. It's possible they could be routing *some* internet addresses through them and not others. It's possible they could change the routing policy every time you connect.

If it's a company computer, it's possible they could be setting policies like browser proxy use to make web requests go through them, but which won't affect traceroute. That might be a feature included in the SonicWall VPN client if it has pre-connection setup scripts, even if it's not a company computer.

Or, most likely, they route the office internal network over the VPN and leave everything else alone.

Comment: Are you high? Or is this simply your way of talking? Thanks anyways for the information.